# Not able to create a spark context - SparkContext hangs, Windows OS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed pyspark on Windows and pyspark-shell works like it supposed to do. No issues there. However, when I try to create context from jupyter notebook SparkContext hangs.

After an interruption, I find that it stops in:
pyspark\java_gateway.py in code marked with such comment:

*# Wait for the file to appear, or for the process to exit, whichever happens first.*

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Some more details on the environment:

- pyspark version 2.3.3 (spark and pyspark equally)
- java 8 (no spaces in the directory name)
- jupyter notebook 5.7.8
- python 3.6.5

I tried also with findspark but with exactly the same result.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

#### UPDATE:

User variables:

- HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\winutils
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_212
- SPARK_HOME = C:\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7

System variables:

- HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\winutils\bin
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_212
- SPARK_HOME = C:\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
- PATH contains C:\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

Comment: How do you manage your env. variables ?

Comment: I put them in the main question in update section.